# show just what can a div hold

Tags: jquery, css, html

Hi all readers of my post,

How to limit the size of a div that it cannot hold more content, if content is big then it'll be disappear, show just what can a div hold, right?

Thanks 4 u all.

Comment: Hi Kyle. Don't forget to mark as answer as the accepted solution if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specify the width and height that you want, and then use the css property

```
overflow: hidden
```

to hide the rest.

Comment: you can also use `overflow: scroll` etc. See http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/

Comment: There are also options that govern how the text reacts to being enclosed. Do you want the text to be cut off? Would you like it cut off to the nearest word? Or perhaps an ellipsis? Check out `text-overflow`: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html.

Comment: Thnak u all Yanick Rochon and  sscirrus, u gave me new things to know.